# Oracle SQL Trigger with IF Comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a trigger TR_rate, that checks a "features" field on new rows as they are inserted and adjusts a rate based on the features included.

The features field can contain multiple values, and I want the condition to apply for each value. So if the field contains 'Feature1, Feature2', the rate should go up by 35.

My current code approach only works if there is one feature. How can I rewrite it to accomodate for multiple features?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_rate
BEFORE INSERT 
ON rates_table 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(:NEW.features = 'Feature1') THEN 
        :NEW.rate := (:NEW.rate + 15); 
    IF(:NEW.features = 'Feature2') THEN 
        :NEW.rate := (:NEW.rate + 20); 
    IF(:NEW.features = 'Feature3') THEN 
        :NEW.rate := (:NEW.rate + 30); 
    END IF; 
    END IF; 
    END IF; 
END;
/
```

Comment: A column in a database should never, ever, under any circumstances, contain a comma-separated list of values.  Ever.  You really, really, really want to create a separate table that maps rows in `rates_table` to features (i.e. `rate_feature`).  You could then iterate through the features associated with a particular rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `if` statements to be sequential rather than nested, as well as using `like`:

```
IF(:NEW.features like '%Feature1%') THEN 
    :NEW.rate := (:NEW.rate + 15); 
END IF;
IF(:NEW.features like '%Feature2%') THEN 
    :NEW.rate := (:NEW.rate + 20); 
END IF;
IF(:NEW.features like '%Feature3%') THEN 
    :NEW.rate := (:NEW.rate + 30); 
END IF;
```

However, I would just do this using a `select`:

```
select (new.rate +
        (case when :new.features like '%Feature1%' then 15 else 0 end) +
        (case when :new.features like '%Feature2%' then 20 else 0 end) +
        (case when :new.features like '%Feature3%' then 30 else 0 end)
       )
into :new.rate;
```

You can do the same thing at the PL/SQL level, but this captures the logic in a single statement.

Comment: I assume from his code that you can only have Feature2 if you also have Feature1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat for all three:

```
IF(:NEW.features like '%Feature1%') THEN
```